# Swift notification not coming up on expected date

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to add notifications after x days, however when the expected time for the notification passes I don't get a notification. Sometimes a notification comes through but not in the time that is expected.

I have a caller method **saveChanges** that deletes old notifications when a new watering is logged to prevent outdated notifications from coming through. Then I create a new notification after saving the changes to core data.

Any Help Is appreciated, as I'm not sure where I have gone wrong. I suspect it might have to do with how I add days to the dateComp.

Here is my code for notifications:

```
func saveChanges(logType type:String, plantItem: Plant){
        let updateManager = updateView()
        cancelReminders(for: plantItem)
        
        if type == "Water Log"{
            plantItem.lastWateringDate = Date()
        } else if type == "Fertilize Log" {
            plantItem.lastFertDate = Date()
        }
        
        do{
            try self.moc.save()
        } catch{
            print("something went wrong...")
        }
        
        if type == "Water Log"{
            updateManager.updateDaysWatering(for: plantItem)
        } else if type == "Fertilize Log"{
            updateManager.updateDaysFertilize(for: plantItem)
        }
        
        createReminder(for: plantItem, logType: type)
    }

func createReminder(for plantItem: Plant, logType: String){
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        let stringName = plantItem.name ?? "Your plant"
        if logType == "Water Log"{
            content.title = "Time to Water"
            content.subtitle = "\(stringName) looks thirsty!"
        }
        else {
            content.title  = "Time to Fertilize"
            content.subtitle = "\(stringName) looks hungry!"
        }
        
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
        
        var dateComp = DateComponents()
        dateComp.calendar = Calendar.current
        
        if logType == "Water Log"{
            dateComp.day = Int(plantItem.watering)
        }
        else{
            dateComp.day = Int(plantItem.fertilize)
        }
        
        // show this notification in X days (X being the number of days between watering specified by user on plant creation)
        if dateComp.day == 0{
            let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 5, repeats: false)
            // choose plant name as identifier
            let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: stringName, content: content, trigger: trigger)
            // add our notification request
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
        }
        else{
            let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComp, repeats: false)
            // choose plant name as identifier
            let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: stringName, content: content, trigger: trigger)
            // add our notification request
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
        }
    }

func cancelReminders(for plantItem: Plant){
        let notificationToRemove = [String(plantItem.name ?? "Some Plant")]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: notificationToRemove)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you print the date related to your DateComp, you'll see that it's not the date you want, hence why you don't receive any notification:

```
print(dateComp.date) // prints: Optional(0001-01-02 00:01:15 +0000)
```

You need to create a 'triggerDate' from your dateComp, and then use the new DateComponent to trigger your notification:

```swift
[...]
else{
    guard let triggerDate = dateComp.calendar?.date(byAdding: dateComp, to: Date()),
          let triggerDateComponents = dateComp.calendar?.dateComponents([.day, .minute, .second], from: triggerDate) else {
        return
    }
    
    print(triggerDate) // as of today, and assuming dateComp.day = 2, it would print something like: 2020-11-12 11:22:31 +0000
    
    //                                                           change this 
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerDateComponents, repeats: false)
    // choose plant name as identifier
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: stringName, content: content, trigger: trigger)
    // add our notification request
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
}
```